# How to disable Browser Caching for a specific View in ASP.NET MVC Environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I want to disable Browser Caching in a specific View.

I tried `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` in a controller that returns the View, but that does not work.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Generally, you do this on the *action*, not the view. Is there a really good reason why you want to do it on the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the meta tag directly

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

put that at the top of your header. although the Response.Cache call is supposed to just put that in for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work because the View has the MaterPage. If I put it in the MasterPage than the rest of the views will have the browser cache turned off.
Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: You could cheat and place a timestamp on all of the links to this specific view. Kind of a hack but it would work for anyone who doesn't go to the view directly